# Format of link is changing whenever trying to add it inside the generated document in Spring

Tags: javascript, java, spring-boot, kotlin, document

```
http://localhost:3000/document?id={document.id}&pin={document.pin}
```

I am trying to add the link for my generated document at the end of my document in a format like above using DocumentBuilder and jsEngine.eval() method in Spring. But the link is being changed to the format below when it is being added at the end of my document.

```
http://localhost:3000/document?id={document.id}
in={document.pin}
```

Is &p a special character in DocumentBuilder any ideas?